# Close a Dialog in JavaFX using a button

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a contacts application in JavaFX, I created a dialog which is supposed to open, when I want to call someone and close it with an actuall button, not the buttontype.

I was trying to write the code for it (below) but it just isn't closing the dialog and I have no idea why.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

```
public void showCallDialog(Contact contact){
    contact = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Calling");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    try{
        URL url = Controller.class.getResource("call.fxml");
        loader.setLocation(url);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(loader.load());
        CallController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setNameLabel(contact);
        dialog.show();
        Button button = controller.getEndCallButton();
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println("pressed");//tested if it listens, and this prints out the "pressed"
                dialog.close();
            }
        });
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't load the dialog");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@FXML
public void call(){
    Contact contact = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    showCallDialog(contact);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you pass contact then never use what you are passing and overwrite the object? Because you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dialog` only closes, if a non-`null` value is assigned to the `result` property. This needs to be done "manually" in your code:

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("pressed");//tested if it listens, and this prints out the "pressed"
        dialog.setResult(ButtonType.CLOSE);
        dialog.close();
    }
});
```